# Getting error #include <unicode/ubrk.h> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 1 error generated. make: *** [php_intl.lo] Error 1 ERROR: `make' failed

Tags: php, xampp, php-7.4

I have installed XAMP with PHP Version 7.4 and iterm2 for bash profile.

I'm tying to install php intl extensions using

`sudo pecl install intl`

It's failing with below error

```
/private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/T/pear/temp/intl/php_intl.h:33:10: fatal error: 'unicode/ubrk.h' file not found
#include <unicode/ubrk.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [php_intl.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

My PHP Path is `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php`

Comment: [To build the extension you need to install the » ICU library, version 4.0.0 or newer is required. As of PHP 7.4.0 ICU 50.1 or newer is required.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intl.requirements.php)  I think the header file belongs to ICU library.

Comment: icu4c is already installed. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you install the package with '-devel' suffix? BTW intl is a built-in extension, are you sure your XAMPP doesn't contain it?